# Making a table, 4 cells per row, responsive by moving the third and forth cells into a new row

Tags: html, css

Here's the original table ([fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zvn3Le0r/)):

```
Title    | BookABC  | Author    | Peter
Category | Religion | Publisher | ABC Publisher

<table class="infoTab">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Book ABC</td>
            <td>Author</td>
            <td>Peter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>Religion</td>
            <td>Publisher</td>
            <td>ABC Publisher</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make the table responsive on mobile. Is there any way to move the third and forth cells into a row of its own so in mobile view it would become:

```
   Title    | ABC ABC  
   Author   | Peter
   Category | Religion
   Publisher| ABC Publisher
```

How can I achieve that using css? The fiddle example isn't working using `display: inline-block` and `width:50%`. It turns each cell into a row of its own, like this:

```
Title
Book ABC

Author
Peter

Category
Religion

Publisher
ABC Publisher
```

Css Code:

```
.infoTab{    
    font-size: 14px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width:90%
}
.infoTab td:nth-child(odd) {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.infoTab td{   
    width: 25%;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 700px;
    color: #4D6679;}

@media  only screen and (max-width: 525px) {
   .infoTab td{ 
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .infoTab td:nth-child(3){display:block}
    .infoTab td:nth-child(4){display:inline-block}
}
```

Comment: You could use something like `<div class="hidden-xs">this is hidden on xs screens</div>` but that would make your HTML bigger and having duplicate data. You maybe could redesign your layout of the table. But as your tables (on several screens) are that different, I would use `hidden-XX` classes. Those classes are made by Bootstrap, but I assume you could make them yourself by using mediaqueries and the `visibility` css property.

Comment: I don't think a table is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the CSS width, which excludes padding and border. That is, the actual width of a 50% wide cell is 50% plus 8px for the padding plus 2px for the border. Therefore, two cells don't fit on one line! There's also a space between the two cells.

So the solution is to set `box-sizing: border-box` to include the padding and border in the width, and add `float: left` to get rid of the space.
See [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/zvn3Le0r/2/).

However.

The markup for the table is not good.
Firstly, you shouldn't just put an arbitrary number of cells in a table row just because the layout looks nice. That's not what tables are for.
And secondly, cells that contain property names rather than values should be `th` cells, not `td`.

So that's what the table should look like: two cells per row, a `th` and a `td` to show one piece of data.
And then flip the logic of the css around, so that it looks the way it's designed (with two columns) on narrow screens, but expand to four columns on wider screens.

Another advantage of this method is that you can extend this to show more than four columns on very wide screens.

```css
.infoTab {
  font-size: 14px;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 90%
}
.infoTab th, .infoTab td {
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
  padding: 4px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #4D6679;
}

@media all and (min-width: 526px) {
  .infoTab, .infoTab tbody {
    display: block;
  }
  .infoTab tr, .infoTab th, .infoTab td {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .infoTab::after {
    clear:left;
    display:block; content:'';
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="infoTab">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>     <td>ABC ABC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Author</th>    <td>Peter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>  <td>Religion</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Publisher</th> <td>ABC Publisher</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```